# Bash script to send, move and rename files

Tags: arrays, shell, adb, move

I created a shell script to send xml files to my android emulator.
The intention is to send the file and later move the file to a folder renaming it to know which files were moved.
It happens that when I have more than 1 file, the script ends up skipping sending the first file, renames it and moves it, and then sends the later ones as needed.
Could someone give me some help?

```
files=( $(find "$PWD" -maxdepth 1 -type f) )
        for j in "${!files[@]}"; do
                xmls=( $(ls -p *.xml | grep -v /) )
                for h in "${!xmls[@]}";do
                adb push ${files[$j]} /storage/emulated/0/importxml/${xmls[$h]}
                mv ${files[$j]} ${1}/${xmls[$h]}.ok
                sleep 1 ;done;done
```

Answer (score 0):

well, as I had no answers, I went to fight...
I tweaked the script by eliminating one of the 'for'.
now it's perfect...

```
files=( $(find "$PWD" -maxdepth 1 -type f) )
    for j in "${!files[@]}"; do
            adb push ${files[$j]} /storage/emulated/0/importxml/
            mv ${files[$j]} ${files[$j]}.ok
            mv *.ok ${1}/;done
```